# ActionBarSherlock doesnt worl with AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have added those lines to my build file :

compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'

And i am gettin error every time i am trying to build my project.

Error : Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited.

As i understand actionBarSherlock is trying to rewrite project standart files.
So, the questino is what can i do with this problem?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "by.test.roma.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use ActionBarSherlock, it's deprecated? Use the support lib.

Comment: Its a point in my test.So i cant do other way/

Answer (score 0):

It was conflicting with other support libraries.Also you must have 1.6 java.And its depricated.So my rssParser need java 1.7+,and its more valuable then deprecated lib.sO I just said actionBarSherloc goodby.(To fix this you need to delite supp libraries one by one and find the one you are doubling)